# How can I invert the order of the values of a $list in SASS

Tags: sass

I am trying to invert the order of a given `$list` of values in `SASS`.

I want to apply this in order to invert `shapes`, specifically `clip-path: polygon()`.

I have tried using `@for $i from 1 to length($list)` than tried to invert the order of each interaction:

```
$l: 10% 20%, 30% 40%;

@for $i from 1 through length($l) {
  
  //I tried using the index somehow to invert the order with nth($l, $i) with no success
   

}
```

As I am new to SASS I am still getting used to the environment based on `Ruby`, as I come from a `Javascript` universe.

I would like the following result:

`$l: 10% 20%, 30% 50%` => `30% 50%, 10% 20%` so I can apply this result to my `shapes`.

Thanks!

Comment: As I understand, you want to loop through the list in reverse?

Comment: @Arkellys hello there once more! Yup, this is what I want. I wanna invert the shapes, to create an infinite background on a footer I am implementing =). I am still very new to SASS, and the syntax still confuses me a little, as I am not a ```ruby``` dev =). I am starting to really like more and more the clean syntax offered by Ruby, very cool

Comment: Ahhh yes, hi again! Without seeing the code in your loop I'm not 100% sure to understand exactly what you want to do, but maybe just doing `@for $i from length($l) to 0` and then get the value with `nth($l, $i)` is what you need?

Comment: I must thank you in advance, @Arkellys! You are always teaching me SASS over here =). Please imagine a shape with any values in it, I will place random values e.g: ```clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 30% 20%, 45% 19%, 70% 100%)``` I want to reverse the key-paired values in order to reverse the shape. I have created some shapes to design some hills for a background. I want to reverse the shapes so I can use the reversed shape to connect with the original and create a infinite background effect upon an animation.

Comment: @Arkellys I do not wanna use ```nth($l, $i)```. I wanna invert the order of the values of a given ```list```. I imagine that I would need to store the key pair values that I wanna use in my ```polygon``` in a ```list``` then invert this ```list``` getting the desired result: ```clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 30% 20%, 45% 19%, 70% 100%)``` ```=>``` ```clip-path: polygon(70% 100%, 45% 19%, 30% 20%, 10% 0%)```

Comment: Ahhh I see now, I will write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you supposed, what you can do is first creating a helper function that will reverse your list:

```
@function reverseList($list, $separator:comma) {
  $reversedList: null;
  
  @for $i from length($l) to 0 {
    $reversedList: append($reversedList, nth($l, $i), $separator);
  }
  
  @return $reversedList;
}
```

And then call it where you need:

```
$l: 10% 0%, 30% 20%, 45% 19%, 70% 100%;

.background {
  clip-path: polygon(reverseList($l));
}
```

Compiles as:

```
.background {
  clip-path: polygon(70% 100%, 45% 19%, 30% 20%, 10% 0%);
}
```

Comment: thanks once more! I now understand how this works! I am wondering now how could I mutate each item of the ```$list``` instead. I know that I should use a ```@each``` on this case, but I keep failing in mutating the items.

Comment: @Alioshr [here is a nice resource](https://hugogiraudel.com/2013/08/08/advanced-sass-list-functions/) if you want to learn how to manipulate lists. (:

Comment: you are the best! Thanks for teaching me SASS and sending me this very good quality walkthrough =D  *-*. The official documentation is very nice, but when it gets to more advanced combination of features, it lacks examples, or use cases.

Comment: You're very welcome @Alioshr , I'm glad to help. ^^